# How to import PostgreSQL database dump via node and pg

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to import a PostgreSQL database dump, saved as a plain text file, into psql using the pg package in node.

so far I'm reading in the file as a string, then attempting to import the string via the following method:

```
var sql = fs.readFileSync('./dbDumpOutput').toString();
pg.connect('postgres://localhost:5432/testdb', function(err, client, done){
    if(err){
        console.log('error: ', err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    client.query(sql, function(err, result){
    done();
    if(err){
        console.log('error: ', err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    process.exit(0);
});
```

I'm getting the following error: `error:  { error: syntax error at or near "\"`

Is this a formatting issue with my dbdump that I'll have to parse out, or am I doing something else incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

I got a working solution which I've provided below, using psql instead of pg.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const child = spawn('createdb', ['psqltest']);

child.on('exit', function (code, signal) {
  console.log('child process exited with ' +
              `code ${code} and signal ${signal}`);
  const cat = spawn('cat',['dbDumpOutput']);
  const imp = spawn('psql',['psqltest']);
  cat.stdout.pipe(imp.stdin);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because plain text pg_dump uses `COPY FROM STDIN`, which ends up with `\.`. I think you can't use this `COPY FROM STDIN` brianc's pg module (otherwise there would be no need in [this](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-copy-streams)). you can try specifying `--inserts` on pg_dump to generate inserts instead. But I would recommend just using tools meant for pg_dump generated dump to restore, like `psql`

Comment: I understand how to use psql in the command line, but how can I run my psql commands via node?

Comment: you can spawn a process. just like any other program with arguments